# Automatically passing focus betwen EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofocus

Since my question asking about [separating characters that are typed in an EditText into groups or blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044509/edittext-how-to-separate-characters-that-are-typed-in-a-edittext-in-groups-or/43046077?noredirect=1#comment73208574_43046077) didn't receive much attention, I've come here with another question on an alternative way to accomplish what I need.

So, my idea is to have four EditText that have 4 char length. Now what I want is to change the focus as the user type, from an EdutText to another when the limit is reached. 
Example: Let's say we have EditText A, B, C, D; the first to gain focus is EditText A, then when the chars length at A reach 4, the focus passes to EditText B and so on and stops At D.

I'm trying something like the code bellow, but the focus is not requested when the length reaches 4 chars.

```
inputFieldA.requestFocus();

    inputFieldA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldB.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inputFieldB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldC.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inputFieldC.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldD.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inputFieldD.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length() == 4){
                //send all to Main EditText (A + B + C + D)
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

So I'm here asking if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your conditions in afterTextChanged method and make changes as follows :

```
inputFieldA.requestFocus();

    inputFieldA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(inputFieldA.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldB.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    inputFieldB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(inputFieldB.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldC.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    inputFieldC.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(inputFieldC.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldD.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    inputFieldD.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(inputFieldD.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4){
                //send all to Main EditText (A + B + C + D)
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(inputFieldA.toString().trim().length() == 4){
            inputFieldB.requestFocus();
  }
```

replace this lines in onTextChange() methode.

Comment: Your solution works from A to B only, not from B to C

Comment: means for B to C 
if(inputFieldB.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4){
                inputFieldC.requestFocus();
            }

Comment: I did but on aftertextChanged method, as suggested by @SurajMukhija, It's working now

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding validation on the basis of CharSeq length add validation on the basis of edittext text like this:

replace

```
    if(s.toString().trim().length() == 4)
```

with

```
    if (currEdittext.getText().toString().length() >= 4)
```

Note: update your condition as well.

`currEdittext` will be either `inputFieldA`, `inputFieldB`, `inputFieldC` depending on your requirement

Comment: I've re^placed with what you suggested but nothing's happening. How should I update the conditions?